# Please help me to finished my sentence: article usage and present tense

Tags: sentence-construction, articles, present-tense, present-perfect-progressive

"The main reason for this is the traditional Chinese way of teaching English language tends to stress the importance of grammar and reading practice, but attention paid to speaking probably was even less than a half of that of reading, subsequently, speaking has been becoming more trivial every year since the 80s."

This is the original sentence I wrote, I am not sure about two parts, **1**: *but attention paid to speaking probably was even less than **the** half of that of reading*.
should I use **a**, **nothing** or **the** here?

**2**: *speaking has been becoming*
is it fine to use has been becoming here?

please help with this bit of my essay!

Comment: A friendly reminder: these are two *different* questions; they're only weakly related in that they appear in the same sentence (but a totally different part). You've got your answer now, but in the future, please ask *two* questions.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. You could use this: "even less than half that of the reading".  I'd also consider ending the sentence there and start the next with Subsequently.
2. I am fine with "has been becoming" - sounds good to my ear.

Other points:

> more trivial

doesn't quite work. Consider "more trivialized" as it actually flows well with your statement.

In your opening statement:

> The main reason for this is the...

You have an implied "because" or "that" here

> The main reason for this is because the...

I would include "because", but it is probably ok as-is.